# The type returned by 'operator|' does not always match the type you passed it

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, integer-promotion, bitwise-or

Some code called a templated function, but it did not call the specialisation I expected. Turned out the culprit was this: I or-ed some uint16_t constants and passed them as an argument like this: `foo(uint16_bar | uint16_baz);`. My expectation was it would call the `foo<uint16_t>`, but it did not. I can easily evade the problem with a cast, but I really wonder what the reason for this might be. Especially since not every integral type you pass it will return type int.

**Case 1:**

```
uint16_t a = 2;
uint16_t b = 4;
auto x = (a|b); // x is of type 'int': Surprize!
```

**Case 2:**

```
uint a = 2;
uint b = 4;
auto x = (a|b); // x is of type unsigned_int: What I would expect
```

**Why does (a|b) in case 1 not return a value of type uint16_t ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Comment: *"In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable."* [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual arithmetic conversions are applied to operands of the bitwise operator |. That means that integer objects of types with rank less than the rank of the type `int` are converted either to `int` or `unsigned int` due to the integral promotions that are a part of the usual arithmetic conversions..

From the C++ 14 Standard ( 5.13 Bitwise inclusive OR operator)

> 1 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the
> bitwise inclusive OR function of its operands. The operator applies
> only to integral or unscoped enumeration operands.

and (4.5 Integral promotions)

> 1 A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
> wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
> int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
> the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
> converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int

Answer (score 1):

A quirk of built-in operators is that they will perform integral promotion on small arguments:

[cppreference on implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> prvalues of small integral types (such as `char`) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`). In particular, [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value.

In your code's case, the bitwise OR operator is promoting your `uint16_t`s to `int` before applying the operator.